# C# WPF: ResourceDictionary loaded in designer, but not loaded when I compile in debug mode

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, resourcedictionary

**File:** App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="MyApp.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Dark.xaml"/>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**File:** Dark.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Background.Primary">Red</SolidColorBrush>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**File:** Main.xaml

```
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="local:Main">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource Background.Primary}"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

**File Structure:**

```
Root
  App.xaml
  Main.xaml
  Themes
    Dark.xaml
```

In designer I can notice that the background of my main window turns red, but when I compile the project the background is just transparent !!!

Comment: Can you write down the complete Main.xaml? Something must be conflicting there...

Comment: local:Main is the Current Window, You can use TargetType="Window"

Comment: The implicit `Style` will only be applied to any *child* of the window with a matching type. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you add an implicit `Style` to the `Resources` dictionary of a window, it will be applied to all *children* of the window with a matching type.

But the `Main` window is not a child of itself obviously.

You should set the `Style` property rather than adding the `Style` to `Resources`:

```
<Window>
    <Window.Style> !!! <--
        <Style TargetType="local:Main">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource Background.Primary}"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Style>
</Window>
```

Alternatively, you could just set the `Background` property directly:

```
<Window ... Background="{DynamicResource Background.Primary}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is necessary to set window background try:

```
<Window ... >    
    <Window.Background>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="Background.Primary" />
    </Window.Background>  
    ...
</Window>
```

or this works as well:

```
<Window ...        
    Background="{StaticResource Background.Primary}">
    ...
</Window>
```